# Using gf with Webpack aliased directories

Tags: vim

I have an alias `common-components` defined in my webpack, which resolves to `static/js/components`. I want to be able to use `gf` to open imported files using the alias (ex. `common-components/button/button.jsx`). My research has pointed me in the direction of using `includeexpr` and `suffixesadd` in .vimrc like so:

```
set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'^\\common-components','static/js/components','')
set suffixesadd=.js,.jsx
```

However, using `gf` when hovered over the path gives me an error:

```
E65: Illegal back reference 
E447: Can't find file "common-components/button/button.jsx" in path
```

Not sure where to start looking, as I can't seem to find the function signature for `substitute`, so I'm not positive where to begin debugging.

I use [vim-js-file-import](https://github.com/kristijanhusak/vim-js-file-import), and would like to be able to import files while respecting the alias too. As an example, hovering over a React component and hitting `<leader>if` (the mapping for import under cursor) should import the file at the top, using `common-components/button/button.jsx`.

Answer (score 2):

```
set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'^common-components','static/js/components','')
```

should turn this:

```
common-components/button/button
```

into this:

```
static/js/components/button/button
```

then, Vim should look for:

```
static/js/components/button/button.js
static/js/components/button/button.jsx
```

in the directories in your `:help 'path'`.

The `\\`  in your pattern is preventing the substitution from working so you get `v:fname` unchanged, which Vim can't find because it doesn't exist.

Comment: You have to escape spaces in `set`, or avoid them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this solution doesn't work. When I source the newly edited .vimrc, I get `Unknown option: '^common-components'`

Comment: Removing the spaces should help. @Tycholiz

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't see anywhere that I am using spaces in the above snippet

Comment: @Tycholiz Look at the history of my answer: the initial version had spaces, which were causing the error you reported. I removed them in the meantime.